# google api - storing and using the refresh-token

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, google-api, refresh-token

I've been using the google api, and came across a problem where
I want to store the refresh token that I receive from the google servers without using a database

the option I've found that people use is storing in a local file, I've tried doing so, ran in a bunch of errors, that I haven't found a place to solve it.

[image: Line 47 - crashes my app]

[image: this is the error I've been getting:]

My question is - how do I store a refresh token in a local file (.json file)
and how after storing the token, can I produce a new access token/using the google api again.
I've read somewhere that when using the generateAuthUrl -> with access_type: offline
it handles it by itself, but how before getting the refresh token it can do that

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please do not include code as image files. Stackoverflow editor has features to support inserting code blocks. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: The node.js sample for drive shows how to store the tokens https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/nodejs

Comment: @DaImTo nothing there helps my problem